# debug a service windowns through your source code DELPHI?

Tags: windows, delphi, debugging, service

can someone help me how do I debug a service windowns through your source code DELPHI?
Ie I need to debug a windows service in delphi.

Comment: [`How to debug a windows service with Delphi?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2884631/576719). See also [`Debugging Service Applications`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Debugging_Service_Applications).

Comment: The simple answer is that you don't. Write your service so that it can be run as a desktop app, and debug that. At least, that's the answer if by "debug" you mean step through in the IDE. There are of course literally hundreds of meanings of the word debug.

Comment: You CAN debug a service in the IDE, you just cannot start the service from the IDE. You have to start the service normally via the SCM, then you attach the debugger to the service process afterwards. I do it all the time. If I need to debug the service's startup code, I usually add an input parameter to the service that makes the service code wait for the debugger to attach before then continuing. Yes, making a service be debuggable as a standard app can be convenient at times, but there are also times when an app cannot do things that a real service needs to do. Use what works for you.