# Delphi: Timer in Service Stops my FileReader

Tags: file, delphi, timer, windows-services, filereader

I am writing a Service that has a Timer which should check every 60 seconds if a Line has a particular number. Here is the code of the timer:

```
procedure TConnectionChecker.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  myFile: TextFile;
  sLine: string;
  fileOpenLog: TStreamWriter;
  fileOpenLogName, fileOpenLogPathName: string;

begin
  ExePath := TPath.GetDirectoryName(GetModuleName(HInstance));
  filename:= 'restult.txt';
  filePath:= TPath.Combine(exePath, 'OutputFile');
  filePathName:= TPath.Combine(filePath, filename);
  fileOpenLogName:= 'Log_fileOpen.txt';
  serviceLogPath:= TPath.Combine(exePath, 'LogFiles');
  fileOpenLogPathName:= TPath.Combine(serviceLogPath, fileOpenLogName);
  fileOpenLog := TStreamWriter.Create(TFileStream.Create(fileOpenLogPathName, fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite));

  if not FileExists(filePathName) then
  begin
    fileOpenLog.WriteLine('File not found');
    TServiceThread.Current.Terminate;
    fileOpenLog.Free;
  end;
  fileOpenLog.WriteLine('File found');
  try
    AssignFile(myFile, filePathName);
    Reset(myFile);
    fileOpenLog.WriteLine('File opened');

    while NOT eof(myFile) do
    begin
      PingWorkedAufrufe:= PingWorkedAufrufe + 1;
      readln(myFile, sLine);
      fileOpenLog.WriteLine('Read Line: ' + sLine);
      checkIfPingWorked(sLine);
    end;
    fileOpenLog.WriteLine('EOF');

  finally
    CloseFile(myFile);
  end;
  fileOpenLog.Free;
end;
```

And here is the code of my Procedure: checkIfPingWorked:

```
procedure TConnectionChecker.checkIfPingWorked(ALine: String);
var
  AValue, StartOfLineToFind: String;
  checkIfPingWorkedLog: TStreamWriter;
  checkIfPingWorkedLogName, checkIfPingWorkedLogPathName: string;
begin
  ExePath := TPath.GetDirectoryName(GetModuleName(HInstance));

  StartOfLineToFind:= '    Pakete: Gesendet =';
  ip:= '...';
  fileName:= 'restult.txt';
  filepath:= TPath.Combine(exePath, 'OutputFile');
  filepathname:= TPath.Combine(filepath, fileName);
  serviceLogPath:= TPath.Combine(exePath, 'LogFiles');
  checkIfPingWorkedLogName:= 'Log_checkIfPingWorked.txt';

  checkIfPingWorkedLogPathName := TPath.Combine(serviceLogPath, checkIfPingWorkedLogName);
  checkIfPingWorkedLog := TStreamWriter.Create(TFileStream.Create(checkIfPingWorkedLogPathName, fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite));
  checkIfPingWorkedLog.WriteLine('Zeilen werden überprüft');
  if Pos(StartOfLineToFind, ALine) = 1 then
  begin
    AValue:= Copy(ALine, 39, 1);
    if AValue = IntToStr(5) then
      checkIfPingWorkedLog.WriteLine('Success')
    else
    begin
      checkIfPingWorkedLog.WriteLine('Error');

      //Writing E-Mail...
      //Authentifizierung
      IdSMTP1.AuthType := TIdSMTPAuthenticationType.satDefault;

      //Benutzerdaten für Authentifizierung
      IdSMTP1.Username := '...';
      IdSMTP1.Password := '...';

      //Server-Daten
      IdSMTP1.Host := '...';
      IdSMTP1.Port := ...;

      IdSMTP1.Connect;

      try
        IdMessage1.From.Address := '';
        IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := '';
        //IdMessage1.CCList.EMailAddresses := '';
        //IdMessage1.BCCList.EMailAddresses := '';
        IdMessage1.Subject := '--AUTOMATISCHE BENACHRICHTIGUNG--';
        IdMessage1.Body.Text := 'Der PC mit der IP: ' + ip + ' konnte nicht mehr erreicht werden';
        IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
      finally
        IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
      end;
      checkIfPingWorkedLog.WriteLine('Email sent');
      TServiceThread.Current.Terminate;
    end;
  end;
  checkIfPingWorkedLog.Free;
end;
```

But I can only read the first two lines and then it stops.

Important to say is that I originally wrote this as a normal Program. And it worked fine. Now I am converting it into a Windows Service.

Comment: How do you know it is blocked on FileReader?

Comment: This won't solve uour problem, but I think you should make use of FindFirstChangeNotification on your file to avoid polling it. You'll be notified each time the file is updated. Then you analyze it. This consume much less resource than a scan always strategy.

Comment: @fpiette I made a lot of Log files and all are ok only the one in filereader is not

Comment: Do you know which line exactly in the code you show where it blocks?

Comment: I dont know exactly. I tried to put the line i need in the text file to the beginning and it worked fine. So I am pretty sure that it is a problem in the while not eof loop in my timer

Comment: I don't think a GUI timer is what you want in a service. Does your service even have and service a message queue? And yeah, you should avoid polling.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thx for your comment. I know that I anew assign many variables in the procedures. I had the problem that many variables like exepath had no value out of a procedure. So I gave them their value in every procedure where i needed them. 

fileopenlog.writeline is out of the If block. Is this a problem if I give it free if the file was not found? The service should stop anyways.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am new to services and I had no clue how repeat the procedure in time. So I did it like in a normal Program. ^^ I've never heard of message queue ^^ I try to familiarize myself with this topic :)

Comment: You told you convert a normal application to a service. There are two types of normal application: console mode and GUI. If not already a console mode program, first port your application to a console mode application. This will be easy to debug.

Comment: Also, the answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884631/how-to-debug-a-windows-service-with-delphi may help you.

Comment: @fpiette thank you for the Tipp. I will try it :)

Comment: @SebastianSchwayer `TTimer` runs in the thread that creates it. If you place a `TTimer` on a `TService` at design-time, the `TTimer` will run in the project's main thread (the one that calls `TServiceApplication.Run()`), not in the service's own worker thread (the one that fires the `TService` events), so you have to be careful to make sure your timer code is thread-safe, ie synchronizing/serializing access to any resources shared with other threads, such as your files. If you want the `TTimer` to run in the service's thread, create the `TTimer` at runtime in the `TService.OnStart` event.

Comment: @SebastianSchwayer otherwise, consider having your service thread run a loop that uses a [Waitable Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects) to know when to run code periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was, that I created everywhere and everytime new Log Files.
Now I Create one Log file on Service Create:

```
procedure TConnectionChecker.ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  logFilePathName, logFileName, exePath, logFilePath: String;
begin
   ExePath := TPath.GetDirectoryName(GetModuleName(HInstance));
   logFileName:= 'log_connectionTest.txt';
   logFilePath:= TPath.Combine(exePath, 'logFile');
   logFilePathName:= TPath.Combine(logFilePath, logFileName);

   if not TDirectory.Exists(logFilePath) then
    TDirectory.CreateDirectory(logFilePath);

   swLogFile:= TStreamWriter.Create(TFileStream.Create(logFilePathName, fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite));
end;
```

And I made a procedure where I ask for 2 params (destination and text) and write the line to the Log file.:

```
procedure TConnectionChecker.WriteToLog(destination, Text: string);
begin
  swLogFile.WriteLine('[' + DateTimeToStr(now) + '] ' + destination + ' schreibt: ' + text);
end;
```

Finally I can call it in every procedure:

```
 WriteToLog('checkIfPingWorked', 'Success')
```